# Stripe Payment Extra charge

Tags: authorization, stripe-payments, capture, strip

I would like to ask you related to Stripe functionality.
As my Website is in WP and it is related to Laundry. If user come to my site and pay me around 50$ for 20 lbs. When I weigh his clothes at Laundry, it will found 27 lbs. Now I want to charge him extra fees for 7 lbs that found more.
Is It Feasible in Stripe to charge Extra amount from user manually ? 
I am dev and expert in PHP,so I just want to get an idea.
(**I don't want to use calculation on product page with the weigh relates to amount.before Checkout, because, have to weigh again on my Real Laundry Store.**)

This scenario will be If user try to be over-smart or by mistakenly. On that case, I want to charge him extra.
Or any Suggestion will be Appreciable.

Regards
Boyka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Stripe dashboard as well to add an extra charge to this scenario, if you don't want to deal with this within your Wordpress app.

If you setup the stripe charge with a customer object attached (and save the customer_id so you can identify it from your app), you can navigate to the customer > cards page and initiate a charge from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely do this using Stripe. The best solution for your use case it to separate the authorization and charge phases of the transaction. This is exactly what happens when you use your credit card at a gas station. The station will authorize (or in common parlance, but a hold on) a large, but plausible purchase (say $60). Then when you've filled your tank they complete the charge for the actual (smaller) amount.

In your case, I'd authorize an amount 30-50% higher than the user claims (as determined by your knowledge of how wrong people tend to be). You then have 7 days to the second to capture (i.e., complete) the charge, which can be for any amount less than the maximum authorized.

You can read more about the process in [the Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-capture), but the long and short of it is:

```
# to authorize
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u sk_test_YOUR_KEY_HERE: \
   -d amount=8000 \
   -d currency=usd \
   -d description="Example charge" \
   -d capture=false \
   -d source=tok_visa

# to capture
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges/ch_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS/capture \
   -u sk_test_YOUR_KEY_HERE: \
   -d amount=5000
   -X POST
```

### A couple notes

- You don't want to go too crazy when setting your authorization amount (e.g., 300%) as this money will not be available to your customer. If they have a low credit limit, this can be a real hassle.
- You should [save your Customer's card information](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards) so that you can create a new charge for the Customer should the amount be larger than the ~50% buffer you give yourself. If you do this, be sure to [refund the original authorization](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#create_refund) so that your customer has that money available as soon as possible on their credit card.